# Use MFC in a static library option in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017, mfc, advapi32

I'm trying to link my code (a DLL project) against mbedtls library with **"Use MFC in a Static Library"** option (Project settings -> General -> Use of MFC) and getting "unresolved external symbol" errors (the functions are from advapi32.lib). If I add advapi32.lib to the linker input, the code links fine, but dependency walker shows me dependence in advapi32.dll... kind of loosing the point of "static linkage". It seems that this option only replaces the **/MD** flag by **/MT** and only statically links the runtime lib code... What am I missing here?

When compiling mbedtls lib I choose "Use MFC in a Static Library" and build in Debug mode (static lib).
When compiling my code I choose "Use MFC in a Static Library" and build in Debug mode (DLL).

Thanks!

Comment: "*dependence in `advapi32.dll`*" That's a system DLL, which will always be linked dynamically. The `/MT` vs. `/MD` options only affect the C/C++ runtimes.

Comment: Dependency Walker is quite useless these days. It was never updated to support [API sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-apisets) introduced starting with Windows 7.